# Handle failures in Event Driven Architecture

Tags: design, domain-driven-design, event, event-handling, failure

Suppose you have a bounded context with ~30 business events and, for simplicity sake, the same number of commands like `ChangeUserEmailCommand` -> `UserEmailChangedEvent` initiated from a web UI. Processing a command may fail for the following main reasons (besides infrastructure failures of course):

1. Validation issue (email uniqueness)
2. Technical issue (optimistic concurrency version mismatch)

I'd be interested to provide the best user experience to the clients and display what went wrong.

What is the best practice to signal the failures?

1. Would you create 30 more events like `ChangeUserEmailFailedEvent`? If not, what's your rule of thumb for which events to create a paired `*FailedEvent`?
2. Is it a good idea to just have `bool Success {get;set;}` property in the existing events? It's probably not the best way when you need to signal more failure details than just an error message
3. Would you create a single `ConcurrencyFailedEvent` for all concurrency issues adding a source command type as part of it's payload? Just to separate this kind of failure from business validation failures?

The commands are processed asynchronously (via a broker). The read storage is separated from the write storage. No event sourcing.

As for why would I need this I can think of the following:

1. Detailed error message pushed back to a client via web sockets, for example
2. Threat detection - reacting to an increased number of failed user registration which might be an attack
3. Monitoring - displaying a number of failed orders on a dashboard, for example. If it's within a certain range I'd feel safe letting the support handle it. If it's above a certain number - I probably need to dig the logs.

Comment: As usual: It depends. What are your requirements? Please add more details to your question.

Comment: Thanks, updated as much as I could. Imo, these requirements are rarely part of what engineering teams get as an input. I hope to hear some practical advice from whoever built real life systems with EDA because there is not much information on the subject in those dozens of videos/article I've read so far.

Comment: There are also non-formal requirements to consider. It seems that you want to notify event listeners when an action failed (wich would normally lead to an event). Why do you want to achieve this? Is it important? What should event listeners do when they are notified about a failed action?

Comment: How are your commands processed? Synchronously or asynchronously? Do you have eventual consistency implemented?

Comment: @Andy, Thanks for clarifying! Added extra details.

Comment: And there's also logging, which can be monitored for failures as well.

Comment: I'd compose an answer, but I first have to understand why a `UserEmailChangedEvent` would get raised in the case where the `ChangeUserEmailCommand` fails? Obviously the user's email has not changed.

Comment: @king-side-slide, `ChangeUserEmailCommand` may succeed or fail. We can have a pair of `UserEmailChangedEvent` and `ChangeUserEmailFailedEvent`. Or just a single event `UserEmailChangedEvent` with a property `Success`. Or even a generic `FailEvent` for all event types in the sustem. I'm interested in hearing which approach people took in their solutions.

Comment: Why have you chosen to process commands asynchronously? Walk me through the process here: A web page sends an `XMLHttpRequest` to an endpoint with a `ChangeUserEmailCommand` message? Then that endpoint, rather than processing the command, forwards the command to a _different_ machine? This machine processes the requests, and enqueues any associated events to yet _another_ machine? And all-of-the-above occurs async such that none of the "requestors" are able to glean any response information?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me like you can get away with a single type

```
ErrorEvent
    EventId
    ErredEventId
    ErrorType
    Message
```

If you just have generic errors to deal with, but I would go further and remove Error events for UI stuff.

If the user is waiting to see if something erred you can pass the error back from the function they called and only write the event on success.

So, just `EmailUpdated` instead of `EmailUpdateRequest` `EmailUpdateFailed` `EmailUpdated` etc etc

You can see how going fully event driven can explode the number of types you need. If they are all internal to a thick client, then you have compile time checking to handle it all, but if you have to pass them over a distributed system it becomes ridiculous

Comment: I think it boils down to:  Can the user recover from the error?  If no, all they need is a message saying "an error occurred".  They can't do anything anyway, so alert and tell them to try again later.  If they can recover then you need the message and other data to determine what to do next as indicated here.

Comment: Id say its more, can the system self recover. If there is a human they can read the mesage. If its a computer they need structured data

Answer (score 1):

1. From your question I've understood `ChangeUserEmailFailedEvent` is a core part of your domain. So it should be always stored. The thing is that you can't predict how your business requirements will change so it's better to store your domain events just in case.
2. Not sure what `bool Processing {get;set;}` means. In case it's not a domain concept - better omit it.
3. Technical issues should not be stored in event logs as there are no business values in them. For tech-related stuff, you should maintain separate application log. (I mean like plain text files or Elastic APM logs or Logstash. I hope you get my point).

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "it should be always stored"? I'm not using Event Sourcing. As for #2 - it was a typo, my bad (should be `Success`, renamed the property).

Comment: "I'm not using Event Sourcing" - my bad, missed that. Still, I'd stick to firing all those events that are used by business domain. Regarding Success property, I think it's better to pass some sort of EventArgs class with all info needed to handle the event correctly